# VBA Copy visible cells and paste as values - most efficient method

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I have an excel tool that uses feed from 11 different raw data files generated from reporting system to do some calculations on that data.

The process is very simple:
- open file
- filter contents
- copy filtered contents
- paste into another file (the summary tool's tab)

As the amounts of data and individual files rose I started getting more issues with memory.Hence my question - what is the most memory and speed efficient way to copy/paste these tables?

- (...).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=(...) - I haven't found the way to include XLValues parameter for this (I want to minimise the resources taken up by copying formatting, there are no formulas)
- using defined ranges for the copy/paste purpose (name range with xlCellTypeVisible parameter, converting to another range to get the values only and sending the range to destination) - that would require additional variables for the ranges
- plain old Columns(...).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy and Range.("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues - this method has both "only visible cells" and "paste values only" bits that I'm looking for, but it uses the clipboard as a middleman and I guess this is eating up my memory

Maybe there is yet another method that I don't know of?

Appreciate any insights!

Comment: There are numerous ways to accomplish the task of combining data. You could use arrays or a custom function which does the 'calculation on the data' and pulls only the result into the 'summary tool'? Or, step outside of VBA and use power query, or a database. This question seems too broad.

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately there is a built-in feature for Autofilter to facilitate this.  Say we start with:

[image]

and apply a filter to it with:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Columns("A:B").AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$B$8").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=">50", Operator:=xlAnd
End Sub
```

[image]

**==>** The Autofilter has a `Range` property that allows: **<==**

```
Sub Kopy()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range
    rng.Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
End Sub
```

The result on `Sheet2` has

1. only the visible data from `Sheet1`
2. the header row
3. is not filtered

[image]

**NOTE:**

Looping is not required.
Similar approach can be used for `Tables`.
SpecialCells is not required.

Comment: I'm researching as much as I can about proper syntax for Excel `Tables`, and now the `AutoFilter` built-in feature.  However, I can't seem to find anything in regards to your statement about copying the visible cells and pasting values. Could you provide a reference please?